ActiveMQ Artemis address size is very different from sum of queue persistent sizes?
I'm working with AddressControl and QueueControl objects in Artemis v2.32.0, and I noticed some surprising behavior with respect to sizes. I expected that for one queue, QueueControl#getPersistentSize() would be equal to (at least roughly) AddressControl#getAddressSize().
I have a simple setup where I have a single multicast address (only one queue bound) and send 400K small string messages to it without a consumer acking any. In this setup, I see the AddressControl#getAddressSize() at ~900MB and QueueControl#getPersistentSize() at ~300MB, seems as I vary the message counts the persistent size of the queue is consistently about 3x smaller than the address size.
Message counts between the two are consistent and correct: both show the same number (400K) messages.
I'm not sure which size is to be trusted and why they are differing so much. Briefly looking at the code it seems like the AddressControl#getAddressSize() does some estimation methodology, but it doesn't explain the very different results in practice.

AddressControl#getAddressSize() and QueueControl#getPersistentSize() are really measuring two different things, although they are related since they both involve messages.
AddressControl#getAddressSize() measures (an estimation of) the amount of memory (i.e. JVM heap) consumed by the all (both persistent and non-persistent) messages in all the queues bound to a particular address. It is used to determine when, for example, to begin paging based on the max-size-bytes for the address.
QueueControl#getPersistentSize() measures the amount of disk consumed by the persistent messages in the queue (both in paging and in the journal).

Thanks for the response. It doesn't seem this is the behavior I'm seeing in practice, but I may have misconfigured something. I have DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT set for my only producer and I have persistence disabled for the broker entirely, and see this QueueControl#getPersistentSize() to be about 1/3 of the getAddressSize(). It also felt like it represented non-persistent messages as well based on the docs: "The persistent size of a message is the amount of space the message would take up on disk which is used to track how much data there is to consume on this queue"

I've created a minimal reproducible example here, I hope this makes it easier to see the cause.
